# Displaying multiple pages wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have situation where I've the Page's IDs. But I'm unable to retrieve those pages title properly please have a look.

```
$check = $data['query']; 
echo $check;
```

this displays : 101, 103, 105, 107, 109

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array($check)));
?>
  <div class="menu">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>          
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this code displays the title of the first ID. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll just need to update one line.  The `post__in` takes an array of data and you're passing in an array with the first item being an array.

This line:

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array($check)));`

Should be:

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => $check));`

That printed out the entire array of post titles for me.

So, I just noticed you're printing out a string in the echo.  You'll need to turn that into an actual array by updating your `$check` variable to:

```
 $check = explode(',',$data['query']);
```

That will give you an array to supply to the `post__in` part of your query.

Comment: Just to clarify the final code for the query will look like this:

    `$check = explode(',',$data['query']);
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => $check));`